# Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Abhishek Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe manage.py runserver'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use runserver command over vs code terminal. But now it is giving me the error. " Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Abhishek Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe manage.py runserver'". But I have the python interpreter in my environment path. Also, I have my virtual environment which I created while initiating the project but still and using the interpreter in my environment I was getting the same error..

Please help me out with that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmmSB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try running server on cmd. Go to Folder and type python manage.py runserver.
(Instead of use py use python or python3)